# How To Insert Some Content Before An HTML Element In The Runtime Using CSS

Tags: html, css

Suppose the HTML defined as

```
<div>
  <div class="runtime"> Some Important Text.Insert "Important" Before This </div>
  <div class="normal"> General Text </div>

</div>
```

So Generally The Output Would be

> Some Important Text.Insert "Important" Before This
>
> General Text

But After Rendering It should Show Us

> **Important Generated Content**
>
> Some Important Text.Insert "Important" Before This
>
> General Text

I am looking for only css solution.

Comment: @ManishMishra That's completely wrong. Yes, you can.

Comment: @ManishMishra Yes you can, it's not always advisable and the above is not cross-browser compatible, but you can do it.

Comment: wow, i nvr did 'before'.:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for this

```
.runtime:before{
    content: "Important Generated Content";
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
}
```

*Yes, you can add some `margin-bottom` as the other answers suggested.
I'd feel like committing plagiarism if I change my code directly. Just annotate here.*

You may guess, there's before, is there after?
The answer is yes!

You can do things like

```
.importantStuff:after{
    content: "!!!!!";
}
```

This adds `!`s at the end of `importantStuff` class

One last thing, every element can only have exactly **one** `before` and **one** `after`, so use them wisely. And enjoy using CSS.

Answer (score 4):

```
.runtime:before {
    content: "Important Generated Content";
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Please see this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b4prD/).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the pseudo-class `:before` with the `content` property.

```
.runtime:before { 
    content:"Important!";
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

You can view the browser support here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent

You might want to have a look at [this guide](http://css-tricks.com/css-content/), for a little more infomation and better understanding of this property! It explains the use of special characters, ect. You should beaware that they cannot be transitioned or animated.

Answer (score 2):

Use pseudo-class

```
.wrap:before{
    content:"Important Generated Content";
    font-weight:bold
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2sM4k/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery also...

```
$('.runtime').before('<p>Test</p>');
```

Comment: He or she stated "I am looking for only css solution."

Answer (score 0):

CSS cannot change the content on the page, you want JavaScript for this. You can however use the `:before` pseudo-element to create a 'fake' element before the element and add content to it using the `content` CSS rule.

```
.runtime:before{
    content: "Important Generated Content";
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[Some people](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/content.html) have problems with this as CSS was never meant to insert content into a page, only 'style' it. It is certainly more convenient doing this in CSS over JavaScript it comes with one major setback, **users that use assistive technologies may have issues** as outlines in this [blog post](http://cssgallery.info/testing-the-accessibility-of-the-css-generated-content/) and the generated content within the pseudo-elements will not be read.

The alternative method is to generate the label using JavaScript. This example creates a `<p>` element above all tags with the class `.important`.

[See on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dcfQq/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="important">I'm very important</div>
<div>I'm not</div>
<div class="important">I'm very important</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.important').before('<div class="important-notice">Important!</div>');
});
```